# R, ggplot, How do I keep related points together when using jitter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

One of the variables in my data frame is a factor denoting whether an amount was gained or spent.  Every event has a "gain" value; there may or may not be a corresponding "spend" amount.  Here is an image with the observations overplotted:
[image]

Adding some random jitter helps visually, however, the "spend" amounts are divorced from their corresponding gain events:

[image]

I'd like to see the blue circles "bullseyed" in their gain circles (where the "id" are equal), and jittered as a pair.  Here are some sample data (three days) and code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ccode<-c(Gain="darkseagreen",Spend="darkblue")
ef<-data.frame(
  date=as.Date(c("2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-02","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03","2021-03-03")),
  site=c("Castle","Temple","Temple","Temple","Temple","Temple","Palace","Palace","Castle","Castle","Castle","Temple","Temple","Palace","Palace","Castle","Castle","Castle","Castle","Castle","Temple","Temple","Palace","Castle","Temple","Temple","Temple","Temple","Temple","Palace","Palace","Castle","Castle","Castle","Temple","Temple","Palace","Palace","Castle","Castle","Castle","Castle","Castle","Temple","Temple","Palace"),
  id=c("C123","T101","T93","T94","T95","T96","P102","P96","C126","C127","C128","T100","T98","P100","P98","C129","C130","C131","C132","C133","T104","T99","P99","C123","T101","T93","T94","T95","T96","P102","P96","C126","C127","C128","T100","T98","P100","P98","C129","C130","C131","C132","C133","T104","T99","P99"),
  gainspend=c("Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Gain","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend","Spend"),
  amount=c(6,14,34,31,3,10,6,14,2,16,16,14,1,1,15,11,8,7,2,10,15,4,3,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,1,NA,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,2,NA,3))
#▼ 3 day, points centered
ggplot(ef,aes(date,site)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=amount,color=gainspend),alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=ccode) +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,15),breaks=c(5,10,20))
#▼ 3 day, jitted
ggplot(ef,aes(date,site)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=amount,color=gainspend),alpha=0.5,position=position_jitter(w=0,h=0.2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=ccode) +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,15),breaks=c(5,10,20))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My main idea is the old "add jitter manually" approach. I'm wondering if a nicer approach could be something like plotting little pie charts as points a la [package **scatterpie**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html).

In this case you could add a random number for the amount of jitter to each ID so points within groups will be moved the same amount. This takes doing work outside of **ggplot2**.

First, draw the "jitter" to add for each ID. Since a categorical axis is 1 unit wide, I choose numbers between -.3 and .3. I use **dplyr** for this work and set the seed so you will get the same results.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(16)
ef2 = ef %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(jitter = runif(1, min = -.3, max = .3)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Then the plot. I use a `geom_blank()` layer so that the categorical `site` axis is drawn before I add the jitter. I convert `site` to be numeric from a factor and add the jitter on; this only works for factors so luckily categorical axes in ggplot2 are based on factors.

Now paired ID's move together.

```
ggplot(ef2, aes(x = date, y = site)) + 
    geom_blank() +
    geom_point(aes(size = amount, color = gainspend, 
                   y = as.numeric(factor(site)) + jitter),
               alpha=0.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = ccode) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 15), breaks = c(5, 10, 20))
#> Warning: Removed 15 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can add some jitter by `id` outside the ggplot() call.

```
jj <- data.frame(id = unique(ef$id), jtr = runif(nrow(ef), -0.3, 0.3))
ef <- merge(ef, jj, by = 'id')
ef$sitej <- as.numeric(factor(ef$site)) + ef$jtr
```

But you need to make `site` integer/numeric to do this. So when it comes to making the plot, you need to manually add axis labels with `scale_y_continuous()`. (Update: the `geom_blank()` trick from aosmith above is a better solution!)

```
ggplot(ef,aes(date,sitej)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=amount,color=gainspend),alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=ccode) +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,15),breaks=c(5,10,20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels= sort(unique(ef$site)))
```

This seems to work, but there are still a few gain/spend circles without a partner--perhaps there is a problem with the `id` variable.

Perhaps someone else has a better approach!